# how to check if a pointer points to a array of structure is empty in c?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

hope my question is readable..

so what I'm doing is insert an item with a unique dataIndex into an array, but before insert it, I need to check if the dataIndex has already been used.

These are two structures I used:

```
typedef struct item {
    float key; // the key for deciding position in heap
    unsigned int dataIndex; // a unique id for each item
} HeapItem;

typedef struct heap {
    HeapItem *H; // the underlying array
    unsigned int *map; //map[i] is the location of item with dataIndex==i
    unsigned int n; // the number of items currently in the heap
    unsigned int size; // the maximum number of items allowed in the heap
} Heap;
```

What I have done to check the dataIndex is this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0;  i < h->n; i++) {
        if (h->H[i].dataIndex == dataIndex) {
            return HEAP_FAIL;
        }
}
```

but this for loop will take O(n) times each time I insert something, so what I want to do is like:

```
if (h->map[dataIndex] != NULL ) {
    return HEAP_FAIL;
}
```

but this code doesn't work.

So my question is how to check whether `h->H[h->map[dataIndex]]` is empty?

and following is the way I allocate H and map:

```
h->H = (HeapItem *)malloc(sizeof(HeapItem));
h->map = (unsigned int *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (h->map[dataIndex] != NULL ) {
    return HEAP_FAIL;
}
```

It will not work, because `h->map[dataIndex]` contains value, and not address, above `if` will check against value `0`. Even if you do not initialize, there will be some garbage value in any location.

So, best way is to initialize with some value, say -1, infinity, or anything you think which will not come in your actual value range.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I got some questions about the pointer. Does it means that when a pointer is point to an address(e.g. *p), I can do  `if (*p == NULL ) ` to check it? And in my code is `h->H[0].key` pointing to a float or pointing to an address?

Comment: @LeaneLi You should check `p == NULL`, because `*p` will have value at that address, so you do not want to check NULL against value, right? You will check it against address.